# Is it necessary to call ObjectOutputStream#close()?

Tags: java, io, heap-memory, java-6, objectoutputstream

I am using Java 1.6.
I am facing some memory heap issues and in the heap dump I can see that [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) objects are consuming more memory.

In my application at some places, I have used `ObjectOutputStream` but missed to close the stream in some of the methods.
So will this impact the performance ??
Will the stream remain open and will it consume Heap Memory ??

Will Java close the stream when the method is finished where `ObjectOutputStream` is used but stream is not closed ??

Comment: Were the answers helpful to you? If yes you should consider accepting one!

Comment: Yes. I have changed the code and following the conventional approach i.e. to close the stream once use is finished.

Answer (score 4):

No, java will not close the stream all by itself.
How badly leaving it open will affect your performance depends on the rest of the code. If the method is often, it will be a serious problem. Regardless of that, it's just way better practice to close your streams.

It's a great reason to upgrade to java 7, where you can write

```
try (ObjectOutputStream stream = ...) {
    ...
}
```

Here java will close the stream for you when you're done with it, no matter how that happens.

Off course you can achieve the same behaviour in java 6 but it's [more work](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html).

Comment: Yes I see that Java 1.7 will close the streams automatically. But currently application is supported on java 1.6. So upgrading to Java 7 is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

**In Java 1.6, looking at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#close()) :**

> close
>
> public void close()
>              throws IOException Closes the stream. This method must be called to release any resources associated with the stream.

`must` is pretty strong, so I would say that yes, you `must` call it.

We can have a look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java#727) :

```
public void close() throws IOException {
   flush();
   clear();
   bout.close();
}
```

It does clean a few things. It also implements the interface [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), which :

> public interface AutoCloseable
>
> A resource that must be closed when it is no longer needed.

So, call the `close()` method.

**Note** : Even if `close()` did nothing I would still call it to give a clear indication in the code that this is not to be used anymore, but that's probably a personal preference.

Comment: I believe that you have misread the question. It is discussing `ObjectOutputStream` rather than `OutputStream` that you reference above. You may want to reconsider your answer.

Comment: @SteveC You are right, thank you for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some comments to [Stef's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31604692/157762):

From another point of view, you may ask yourself: what is the reason for leaving the `ObjectOutputStream` open in some cases? *If you don't use it anymore, then you should definitely `close` it as soon as possible*. It is a good idea to follow this convention.

The `close` method makes sure that there are no references to the stream so the resources can be garbage collected; using it is definitely something you want to do in order to have a healthy memory space.

What I am usually doing is having a `try {} finally {}` without a `catch {}`:

```
public static void closeStream(OutputStream out)
{
    if (out != null) out.close();
}

...

ObjectOutputStream out = null;

try
{
    //do something
}
finally
{
    closeStream(out);
}
```

You can of course use a `catch` block if you need to, or add `throws` to your method. Either way, this way you can be sure that stream resources are released.